# Show that every prime number in the form $a+b$ with $a,b$ divisors of $n$ is distinct and not divides $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Let $n$ a natural number. Suppose that its positive divisors can be partitioned in tuples of the form $(a,b)$ such that the sum $a+b$ is a prime number. Show that every such prime number is distinct and no of them divides $n$.

I have tried to solve this problem for hours, but I can't completely figure out a solution.

I think that with $n=p^k$ the problem can't be solved because in the set $D=(1,p,p^2,\cdots,p^k)$ can't be partitioned in tuples because every sum ($a+b$) can't be a prime. Any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: Examples are hard to come by...I guess $n=10$, pairing up the divisors as $(1,10)$ and $(2,5)$ works. Or $n=6$ with $(1,6)$ and $(2,3)$.  Maybe there are others of this type...

Comment: Easy to prove that such $n$ must be of the form $n=2m$ with $m$ odd.  $30$ is a non-trivial example, as we can have $(1,30),(2,15),(5,6),(3,10)$.

Comment: @lulu: can we generalize the reasonement for $n=2\cdot \prod_{i} p_i^{k_i}$ where $p_i$ is the $i-$ prime factor of $n$?

Comment: I still don't have any sensible way to generate examples.  No proof, for example, that there are infinitely many such $n$.  Even to do the $2p$ case would require a proof that there are infinitely many twin primes.  Worse, you'd need to prove that there are infinitely many Sophie Germain primes that are also the lesser of a twin prime pair.

Comment: To be sure:  one doesn't need to produce infinitely many examples to settle the claim.  I am just trying to understand the condition.

Comment: @lulu: can't we consider only tbe case where $n=2\cdot p_1 \cdot p_2$ and then show that the proprerty holds?

Comment: It does not hold generally.  For instance, $2\times 5\times 11=110$ does not work since $110+1$ is not prime.

Comment: "I think that with n=pk the problem can't be solved because in the set D=(1,p,p2,⋯,pk) can't be partitioned in tuples because every sum (a+b) can't be a prime. "  That's fine.  It's vacuously true if there are no partitions that add to a prime.

Comment: so the partitions don't need to multiply to $n$?  If ignored the $a+b$ is prime and we just partitioned.  Then partitioning $18$ we could do $(1,2),(3,6),(9,18)$?  We aren't required to do $(1,18),(2,9),(3,6)$?

Answer (score 3):

With the factor of $n$ itself, since any divisor other than $1$ has at least one prime factor in common with $n$, the other divisor must be $1$ itself, i.e., you have $(n,1)$ with $n + 1$ being prime.

Next, consider any prime $p$ where $p \mid n$ and set $a = \frac{n}{p}$. As the question states, there's another divisor $b$ where $a + b$ is prime. If $n$ has more than one factor of $p$, then $a$ has the same set of primes which are factors of $n$ so any $b \gt 1$ (since $1$ is already matched up with $n$) must have at least one prime factor in common with $a$ so $a + b$ can't be prime. This shows $n$ can only have one factor of $p$. Also, since all other prime factors of $n$ divide $a$, this means that $b$ can only be $p$ itself to ensure $a + b$ is prime.

This shows $n$ is square-free, with some $m \ge 1$ distinct primes where

$$n = \prod_{i=1}^{m}p_i \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note if you have $a$ being $n$ divided by the product of $2$ primes, each of the primes individually has been used before, and no other prime factor may be used since it's a factor of $a$, so the other value, i.e., $b$, must be the product of those $2$ primes. In general, you can prove by induction on the number of primes that due to any smaller # of primes already being used previously, you have each factor being paired with $n$ divided by that factor, e.g., $a = \frac{n}{b}$ for all factors $b$ of $n$, say with $a \gt b$ for uniqueness. I'll leave proving this to you to do.

As for showing the constructed primes are distinct, assume you have $(\frac{n}{b_1},b_1)$ and $(\frac{n}{b_2},b_2)$ with $b_1 \neq b_2$, with

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{n}{b_1} + b_1 & = \frac{n}{b_2} + b_2 \\
b_2(n) + b_1^2b_2 & = b_1(n) + b_1b_2^2 \\
b_2(n) - b_1(n) & = b_1b_2^2 - b_1^2b_2 \\
(b_2 - b_1)n & = b_1b_2(b_2 - b_1) \\
n & = b_1b_2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This means $\frac{n}{b_1} = b_2$ and $\frac{n}{b_2} = b_1$ so the two pairs are the same with their values just switched around. This confirms that all of the $a + b$ primes must be unique.

As for showing none of these primes divide $n$, first note that $n + 1 \not\mid n$. As for showing none of the other ones divide $n$, consider that one of them do, so you have for some $b_1$ dividing $n$ and integer $k \ge 1$ that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
k\left(\frac{n}{b_1} + b_1\right) & = n \\
kn + kb_1^2 & = nb_1 \\
kn & = b_1(n - kb_1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since $b_1 \mid n$, this means the RHS has at least $2$ factors of $b_1$. With the RHS, as $n$ has only $1$ factor of $b_1$, this means $k$ must have at least one factor of $b_1$, so $k = rb_1$ for some integer $r \ge 1$. However, this would then give

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
rb_1\left(\frac{n}{b_1} + b_1\right) & = n \\
rn + rb_1^2 & = n
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

However, with $r \ge 1$, the LHS is $\gt n$, so it's not possible to be equal to $n$. This shows the assumption must be incorrect, which proves $\frac{n}{b_1} + b_1 \not\mid n$, i.e., none of these primes constructed from the sum of factors divide $n$.

As indicated in several question comments by lulu, since $n + 1$ is prime and $n \neq 1$, this means $n$ must be even. Since it's square-free, this means $n = 2q$ for some odd $q$. Several examples which work are $n = 2(5)$ and $n = 2(3)(5)$, although I also don't know if there are infinitely many such $n$.

Comment: You said "This shows that $n$ can only have one factor of $p$". How does that follow though? If say I have $n=3^2 * 2^2$, can't I let $a=3^2$ and $b=2^2$ and $n$ is clearly not square free in the case. I could let one of my divisors 'snatch up' all the primes having a power $>2$ in the prime factorisation and it could still be that $a+b$ is prime.

Comment: @YipJungHon Yes, you can have $n = 3^2 \times 2$ and let $a = 3^2$ and $b = 2$. However, the question says that *all* positive divisors must be able to be matched up so their sums are primes. For $a = 3 \times 2$, note $b$ can only be $1$ for $a + b$ to be prime, but $1$ must be matched up with $n$, as I state at the start of my question so it's not available. Thus there are no available values of $b$ such that $a + b$ would be prime. This is why $n$ can have only one factor of $p$.

Comment: Oh you're right, though I didn't interpret the question as needing all the positive divisors to work, I assumed that just one tuple was enough.

Comment: The proof that $n$ is square-free is wrong. If $p$ divides $n$ several times it is not true that all other divisors are divisible by $p$. The smallest example $n=36, p=2$. The proof that the sums do not divide $n$ is also wrong. It is not even clear what divides what in your proof.

Comment: @JCAA I never wrote that "all other divisors are divisible by $p$". With your example of $n = 36, p = 2$, then $a = \frac{36}{2} = 18$. Note $n = 36 = 2^2 \times 3^2$ and $a = 18 = 2 \times 3^2$. The only $b \mid n$ where $a + b$ is prime is $b = 1$, but this not available since you need $36 + 1 = 37$. As for the sums dividing $n$, you are correct that I made a mistake with using the factor $k$ on the wrong side. I've now corrected that to appropriately show that none of these constructed primes can divide $n$. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Comment: You only consider sums $p+n/p$ where $p$ is prime.

Comment: @JCAA As I showed, and you also showed in your answer, the pairing of $a$ and $b$ must be where one is a prime and the other is $n$ divided by that prime, i.e., all $a + b$ are of the form of $p + \frac{n}{p}$ where $p \mid n$. As such, I only consider such sums as there are no other sums to work with. I'm not quite sure what the point is with your comment.

Comment: It is not true not all divisors are either primes of $n/p$. For example 210 has divisors 6 and 35.

Comment: @JCAA I'm just having one of those days! You're right that not all divisors are primes or $\frac{n}{p}$, e.g., where the # of prime factors is $\gt 2$. Thanks, once again, for pointing out another one of my mistakes. I've corrected my answer to address that issue.